# Add and remove textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

At onclick event I am adding marker (image pin.png):

```
var relativeX = event.pageX;
var relativeY = event.pageY;
R.image("pin.png", relativeX, relativeY, 22, 22);
```

R in this code is Raphael paper: `var R = Raphael("paper", 500, 500);`

And I have to add also textbox next to this pin. It will be something like description of this marker. There should also be delete icon next to it that would remove both marker and textbox. User can add unlimited number of markers.

How can I add this textbox and icon/button to remove both  marker and it's textbox?

I am using JQuery and Raphael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raphael's ability to handle text is absolutely horrible. I recently had to do something simular for a project, and i ended up using an HTML5 canvas to generate an image, and then load that image into my project.

So say you create your rect in Raphael, then you'll want to generate an image with your description in it:

```
var width = myRect.getBBox().width
var height = myRect.getBBox().height
var canvas = jQuery("<canvas width="+width+"px height="+height+"px />");
var context = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

context.font = "10pt Calibri ";
context.textAlign = "left";
context.textBaseline = "top";

context.fillText("this is text", xPos, yPos);
```

and then you'll want to move it into raphael:

```
var img = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png"); //turns the canvas object into a png and returns the dynamic url 
var bb = myRect.getBBox();
paper.image(img,bb.x,bb.y,300,400)
```

Its not the 'easiest solution in the world.. but i think you'll find that other options are not very fun to deal with.

Other options include

```
var description = paper.text(0,0,"this is text");
```

which may work better for you, but if you're doing any thing with zooming in and out, or even possibly dragging objects, you will have a hard time.

---

as for your adding markers bit, you'll probably want a function that says something like

```
function addMarker(x,y){
  var marker = paper.set();
  marker.push(
    paper.rect(x,y,5,20).attr({fill:"#000"}),
    paper.rect(x,y,10,5).attr({fill:"#000"}),
  );
}
```

and you'll want a click function as well, something like

```
$("paper").click(function(e){
  addMarker(e.offsetX,e.offsetY)
});
```

I hope this helps some. Feel free to comment if you need any more help.

---

edit:

To remove raphael elements, you can use

```
myElement.remove();
```

or even

```
myElement.hide();
```

---

edit:

I thought you might have been looking for an input field... Which is something that Raphael can't handle. So you're going to have to do some work arounds.

If you create an input field and then position it absolutely on top of your raphael program you can achieve this.

```
var textbox = $("<textarea/>");
textbox.css({"z-index" : 2, "position" : "absolute"});
textbox.css("left",myRaphaelElement.getBBox().x)
textbox.css("top",myRaphaelElement.getBBox().y)
$("body").append(textbox)
```

and i imagine you're going to want the user to be able to save what they write.. which is where you'll add a butotn and do something like

```
button.onclick(function(){
  // write code here that involves the bit i wrote earlier in my post
  // that takes textbox.val() as your text.
});
```

better?

Answer (score 1):

I ended using simple javascript:

```
var relativeX = event.pageX;
var relativeY = event.pageY;
 $('.marker').append('<div class="pin_container" style="top:' + relativeY + 'px; left:' + relativeX + 'px;"> <input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" class="pin_textbox"><input type="button" id="remove" class="delete_button" value=" "></div>');
counter++;
$(".delete_button").click(function () {
$(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Operations on text in Raphael are way to much complicated.